# User Authentication for apache axis 2 web service

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

i am stumped on this.
I wish to ask how do i really know that an authentic client is connecting to my web service.
I have successfully set up an HTTPs protocol on my web service and also my apache tomcat server.
However , how do i really authenticate a client dynamically without him giving me a username and password. Example, google authenticates its clients by giving them an api key , with that key they are allowed to use its web services.

I wish to do something similar to that, how do i do it?
Hope you guys can help me out on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this REST or SOAP ?

Comment: its a REST web service

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should look into The Apache Santuario project which is aimed at providing implementation of the primary security standards for XML.

-> This library includes a mature Digital Signature and Encryption implementation. It also includes the standard JSR 105 (Java XML Digital Signature) API. Applications can use the standard JSR 105 API or the Apache Santuario API to create and validate XML Signatures.

You can find more info at the following url 
http://santuario.apache.org/index.html

You can also find an example here :
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/santuario/xml-security-java/trunk/samples/org/apache/xml/security/samples/signature/

specifically look into the KeyResolver feature

The Apache Santuario project is recommended project by Apache Axis.
http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/security.html#Authenticating_the_caller

Comment: hi gourabp , is there anyway to implement this into axis 2 as i see that this is for axis. As i have completed setting up axis 2 , i don`t want to go through the trouble of setting this up again. Also, time constraints don`t allow me to.

Answer (score 0):

What we tried in this situation is to go really Service Oriented .

i.e. We have an Authentication Service which takes input as User Credentials and return  a  session id . For all other Service calls the session id is added in the soapheader block.

soapHeader.addAttribute()

Using this approach

1. We avoided user credentials details to be used every time in service calls.
2. Also the signature of the service is devoid of any authentication data.

In this approach the client application has to authenticate first and use the output , session id for other service calls.

Request : We still haven't completely analyzed the security threat for this approach. Any suggestions / criticisms would be highly appreciated